# Android IllegalStateException thrown on (GlobalApp) getApplication() casting

Tags: android, exception

I got a crash with the following message:

```js
04-17 11:18:19.855: W/dalvikvm(368): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
04-17 11:18:19.925: E/AndroidRuntime(368): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-17 11:18:19.925: E/AndroidRuntime(368): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
04-17 11:18:19.925: E/AndroidRuntime(368):  at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:2072)
04-17 11:18:19.925: E/AndroidRuntime(368):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2408)
04-17 11:18:19.925: E/AndroidRuntime(368):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:8816)
04-17 11:18:19.925: E/AndroidRuntime(368):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
04-17 11:18:19.925: E/AndroidRuntime(368):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
04-17 11:18:19.925: E/AndroidRuntime(368):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
04-17 11:18:19.925: E/AndroidRuntime(368):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
04-17 11:18:19.925: E/AndroidRuntime(368):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-17 11:18:19.925: E/AndroidRuntime(368):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
04-17 11:18:19.925: E/AndroidRuntime(368):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
04-17 11:18:19.925: E/AndroidRuntime(368):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
04-17 11:18:19.925: E/AndroidRuntime(368):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-17 11:18:19.925: E/AndroidRuntime(368): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
04-17 11:18:19.925: E/AndroidRuntime(368):  at com.UturpatShuPepper.LogCat.TheLogCatActivity.onGo(TheLogCatActivity.java:41)
04-17 11:18:19.925: E/AndroidRuntime(368):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-17 11:18:19.925: E/AndroidRuntime(368):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
04-17 11:18:19.925: E/AndroidRuntime(368):  at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:2067)
04-17 11:18:19.925: E/AndroidRuntime(368):  ... 11 more
04-17 11:18:19.925: E/AndroidRuntime(368): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.app.Application
04-17 11:18:19.925: E/AndroidRuntime(368):  ... 15 more
```

I followed with the debugger and see the crash happens in the following code, in the marked line:

```js
// Go button pressed
public void onGo(View v) {
    final EditText et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.filters);
    String filter = "food\\s+[ABC]";
    if(!ValidateText(et, "^\\s*(" + filter + "(\\s+)" + filter + ")?$", "Bad filters")) {
        return;
    }
--->GlobalApp app = (GlobalApp) getApplication(); <--- CRASHES HERE
    for(int i = 0; i &lt; 100; i++) {
       app.addMessage("message number " + i);
    }
```

and according to the log it is caused by ClassCastException.

I defined GlobalApp class as follows:

```js
public class GlobalApp extends Application {

private final ArrayList<String> messages = new ArrayList<String>();

public ArrayList<String> getMessages(){
    return messages;
}

public void addMessage(String msg){
    messages.add(msg);
}
}
```

Why is the casting wrong? What's the right way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your manifest change this one

```
<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
```

with this one

```
<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name" android:name=".GlobalApp">
```

Since you have not stated the android:name for the  the OS looks for the default Application class. In order to point it to your Application subclass you should use android:name attribute.

Comment: I have already done that, I forgot to put it in the question body. But I have it as a second <application> tag, do you mean I should name the  original <application> tag?

Comment: Done it, and it worked, I checked your answer as good. thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should modify the activity line in your manifest to something like

`<activity android:name="GlobalApp" ...`